# book recommendation on data analysis and statistics

Tags: st.statistics, books, reference-request

I am looking for a book on data analysis and statistics.

My objective is to better analyse and understand data over time (like trends or events) and extract useful information from raw statistics. I am not especially interested in forecasting.

Any recommendations?

Answer (score 4):

An oldie but goody is John Tukey's book Exploratory Data Analysis.  It won't tell you everything you need to know, but it has some good basic content.

Answer (score 3):

I have used Bluman's book on Elementary Statisics at the last two colleges where I taught. The book is designed for students with little more than a 9th grade mathematics background and is very effective.

A number of years ago, David Moore published a book on elementary statistics for the American Statistical Association. The book has accompanying tapes that are to be used to  introduce the major topics. This book is also excellent. I believe that if you contact the ASA and tell them that you are an instructor, you can get a FREE copy of the tapes and book for viewing.

There are alot of dogs out there too.

Answer (score 3):

"[Statistical Analysis with R](http://link.packtpub.com/b6ee5s)" & "[R Graphs Cookbook](http://link.packtpub.com/QYSmBR)" serve as an excellent resource for tackling problems in Data Analysis and Statistics using R.

If you are a beginner to R then the first book would be just perfect for you to learn all you need to, about programming in R.

The [R Graphs Cookbook](http://link.packtpub.com/QYSmBR) contains more detailed recepies for creating the most useful graphs using R.

Answer (score 3):

If you are a beginner, I strongly recommend the book The [Cartoon Guide to Statistics](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0062731025). A cartoon book it is though, it gives very amazing introduction and intuitive explanation.

Answer (score 2):

Again, recommendations.  depends on the preknowledge of the questiones, but for the stated purpose, time series and trends analysis, it will be difficult to find an better introduction than ""The Analysis of Time Series: An Introduction, Sixth Edition (Chapman & Hall/CRC Texts in Statistical Science) " by Chris Chatfield. That is a very simple read with a lot of good practical .  There is no lack of more advanced books which can be attacked when Chatfield is mastered.

Answer (score 1):

I used a book called "College Statistics Made Easy" by Sean Connolly. It claims to be the best book in the world for learning statistics and after reading it I can't disagree. Totally different from anything I've seen before. Aimed at a first or second course in Statistics. [https://www.amazon.com/College-Statistics-Made-Easy-Connolly/dp/0993304702](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0993304702)